# .Net core console application Stop-WebAppPool Remote connect via WinRM using Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, winrm

I need help to solve problem to auto-mate deploy .Net Core web app Api to a server.
As you know is impossible to overwrite `.dll` if you not stop `AppPool` before , and there is no solution for that in `IIS` .
Actually by using `PowerShell` I can perform a script to do what I need the script is showed below: 
[PowerShell script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyWq7.jpg)

Actually I need a console application to performe same work , I found that I can use `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` to implement a solution.

```
public static void RunC()
    {
        string us = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //User
        string pw = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";//Passwprd
        string sv = "xxx.x.xx.xxx";//Server
        string apppoolname = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
        //Creazione script PS 
        script.Append("$password = ConvertTo-SecureString \"" + pw + "\" -AsPlainText -Force" + Environment.NewLine);
        script.Append("$user = \"" + us + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
        script.Append("$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user,$password)" + Environment.NewLine);
        script.Append("Enter-PSSession -ComputerName \"" + sv + "\" -Credential $cred" + Environment.NewLine);
        script.Append("Import-Module webadministration");
        script.Append("Stop-WebAppPool \"" + apppoolname + "\"");
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script.ToString());

        //pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject pSObject in results)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());

        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());


    }
```

But I got error show in the image , seams Module is not lodaded or something similar .. 
some one can help me in some way?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the error in the image, but if it is a issue caused by the WebAdministration not being imported this should fix it:

```
#Requires -Modules WebAdministration
```

Place that at the begging of the script and it will try to import the module if it's not available already in the session. Microsoft documentation:

> Specifies PowerShell modules that the script requires. Enter the module name and an optional version number.
>
> If the required modules aren't in the current session, PowerShell imports them. If the modules can't be imported, PowerShell throws a terminating error.

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-7)

Hope it helps, good luck.

Comment: Hi Roque , thank you to answer . i will try it . becuase import after open remote connection as code line --> script.Append("Import-Module webadministration"); don't work for me

Comment: I mean if that doesn't work I dont think this will either, but I't close the script if it was unable to import, if it executes with the `#Requires` then you know is not an issue of the module.